# 1999 GMC Safari Shocks

Tags: gmc, shock-absorber

I have a 1999 GMC Safari 2WD that has 160k on it.  I need to replace the shocks on it.  Does anyone know how to do this and have a recommendation on the type of shocks I should install?  I only drive it about 20 miles a day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rear - on each side, the shock will be bolted to the frame and the axle.

Front - on each side, connected to the lower control arm and the frame.

Easy to get to, but they might be rusty.  Spray the nuts/bolts down with PB.

I usually just go for whatever is cheap by a well known brand (Monroe, kyb, etc.).  Try to keep them all the same brand/product line.  Might want to look for reviews or read forums.

Comment: This is very generic. You should flesh it out with *a lot* more information. I believe the OP is at best a *novice* and wouldn't know how to do what you are suggesting. This would include *PB* ... you and I know what *PB Blaster* is, but the OP won't.

Comment: I was looking for a bit more detail specifically if I needed any special tools.  My fault for the vague post.  Done a lot of belt line type of replacements (water pumps, alternators, etc)  and brakes but this will be my first with suspension.  I am very well acquainted with PB (the stuff is amazing!)